# Deep linking doesn't work on Android marketingcloudsdk

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

I have implemented the React Native SDK and I am successfully receiving push notifications on both platforms.

The issue is I can't catch url in JS side.

```
.setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
                        NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(new NotificationManager.NotificationBuilder() {
                            @NonNull @Override
                            public NotificationCompat.Builder setupNotificationBuilder(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull NotificationMessage notificationMessage) {
                                NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                                    NotificationManager.getDefaultNotificationBuilder(
                                        context,
                                        notificationMessage,
                                        NotificationManager.createDefaultNotificationChannel(context),
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher
                                    );
      

                                String url = notificationMessage.url();
                                Log.i(url, "url");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

                                builder.setContentIntent(
                                    NotificationManager.redirectIntentForAnalytics(
                                        context,
                                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                            context,
                                            new Random().nextInt(),
                                            intent,
                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                                        ),
                                        notificationMessage,
                                        true
                                    )
                                );
                                return builder;
                            }
                        })
                    )
```

Can see "url" logs.

```
 <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:exported="true"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:screenOrientation = "portrait"
    >

      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>

      <intent-filter>
          <data android:scheme="app" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Linking with script works properly, but getInitialURL always return null.